# Google map circle cursor

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create editable circle my google map that suggested this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun

I would like change the cursor to crosshair or png image over the circle shape.
Can I do this any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to `custom` circle cursor, try code as following:

```
    var crosshairShape = {coords:[0,0,0,0],type:'rect'};
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.62279178711505,-5.895538330078125);
    var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:latlng,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,draggableCursor:'crosshair',mapTypeControlOptions:{style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://www.daftlogic.com/images/cross-hairs.gif',
    shape: crosshairShape
    });
    marker.bindTo('position', map, 'center');
```

For more details, please refer to [here](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-centre-crosshairs.htm).